# Approximating the value of the limit of a sequence defined recurrently

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Suppose I have a sequence defined by recurrence, i.e. $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ for some $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f$ is $K$-Lipschitz for some $K<1$. Then $f$ has a unique fixed point $\ell$ and $(x_n)$ converges to it.

Suppose I want to compute the limit of $(x_n)$ up to some degree of accuracy, say $10^{–p}$. How can I find an $n$ such that $x_n$ gives $\ell$ up to $10^{-p}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Banach Fixed Point Theorem we know the existence of $\ell$ as you said. But the proof gives you an estimate of the speed of convergence, namely
$$
|\ell-x_n|\leq\frac{K^n}{1-K}|x_1-x_0|,\qquad n\in\mathbb N.
$$
So all you have to do is to calculate $x_1$ and then choose $n$ so large such that the right hand side becomes small enough to obtain the desired accuracy for $x_n$.

Comment: THank you. I hadn't extracted such a bound from the proof. This is useful.

Comment: You can also use the _a posteriori_ bound $$|\ell-x_n|\le\frac{K}{1-K}|x_n-x_{n-1}|$$.